# What would be the shortest way to sum up the digits in odd and even places separately

Tags: c#, math, for-loop

I've always loved reducing number of code lines by using simple but smart math approaches. This situation seems to be one of those that need this approach. So what I basically need is to sum up digits in the odd and even places separately with minimum code. So far this is the best way I have been able to think of:

```
string number = "123456789";
int sumOfDigitsInOddPlaces=0;
int sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces=0;
for (int i=0;i<number.length;i++){
   if(i%2==0)//Means odd ones
     sumOfDigitsInOddPlaces+=number[i];
   else
     sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces+=number[i];    
{
//The rest is not important
```

Do you have a better idea? Something without needing to use `if else`

Comment: What system, binary, dec, hex? How do you access ith digit from a number? Array?

Comment: I've edited the code, please take a look.

Comment: If you make a `sumOfDigits[2]` array, you could just do `sumOfDigits[i%2] += number[i];` instead of having 2 separate variables for the odd and even count.

Comment: Is this to check divisibility by 11 ? Then you could add the odd and remove the even (or the opposite for that matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int* sum[2] = {&sumOfDigitsInOddPlaces,&sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces};

for (int i=0;i<number.length;i++)
{
    *(sum[i&1])+=number[i];
}
```

Comment: This looks like C++ .Correct me if I'm missing something. Where do you sum the sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces? From *`(sum[i&1])+=number[i];` I can understand that you add all the digits to the first element of the array.

Comment: i&1 is equivalent to i%2  (same in C and C++ and JS and many other languages)

Comment: Yeah, I had just found that too. Thank you. This seems to be the best, shortest and universal approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could use two separate loops, one for the odd indexed digits and one for the even indexed digits.
Also your modulus conditional may be wrong, you're placing the even indexed digits (0,2,4...) in the odd accumulator. Could just be that you're considering the number to be 1-based indexing with the number array being 0-based (maybe what you intended), but for algorithms sake I will consider the number to be 0-based.
Here's my proposition

```
number = 123456789;
sumOfDigitsInOddPlaces=0;
sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces=0;

//even digits
for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i = i + 2){
    sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces += number[i];
}

//odd digits, note the start at j = 1
for (int j = 1; i < number.length; i = i + 2){
    sumOfDigitsInOddPlaces += number[j];    
}
```

On the large scale this doesn't improve efficiency, still an O(N) algorithm, but it eliminates the branching

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps a short explanation/link on why branch-removal is useful/important could be added.

Answer (score 2):

Since you added `C#` to the question:

```
        var numString = "123456789";

        var odds = numString.Split().Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 1);
        var evens = numString.Split().Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 0);

        var sumOfOdds = odds.Select(int.Parse).Sum();
        var sumOfEvens = evens.Select(int.Parse).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you like Python?

```
num_string = "123456789"

odds  = sum(map(int, num_string[::2]))
evens = sum(map(int, num_string[1::2]))
```

Comment: Sure I do, one of my favorites.

Comment: While this is correct, but I was hoping to not have to tie this to a particular language. I was looking for something that'd work on any  language having for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This Java solution requires no if/else, has no code duplication and is O(N):

```
number = "123456789";
int[] sums = new int[2]; //sums[0] == sum of even digits, sums[1] == sum of odd

for(int arrayIndex=0; arrayIndex < 2; ++arrayIndex) 
{
    for (int i=0; i < number.length()-arrayIndex; i += 2)
    {
       sums[arrayIndex] += Character.getNumericValue(number.charAt(i+arrayIndex));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Having 0/1 in the outer for loop isn't really unique to Java.

Comment: @Teepeemm I haven't said this solution is *unique* to Java - in fact I deliberately tried to make it applicable to as many languages as possible. However, the code *is* Java and not pseudo code which is potentially helpful to future readers. The question asker changed their tags to include C# after the original question was written.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming number.length is even, it is quite simple. Then the corner case is to consider the last element if number is uneven.

```
int i=0;
while(i<number.length-1)
{
    sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces += number[ i++ ];
    sumOfDigitsInOddPlaces += number[ i++ ];
}

if( i < number.length )
    sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces += number[ i ];
```

- Because the loop goes over i 2 by 2, if number.length is even, removing 1 does nothing.
  If number.length is uneven, it removes the last item.
- If number.length is uneven, then the last value of i when exiting the loop is that of the not yet visited last element.
- If number.length is uneven, by modulo 2 reasoning, you have to add the last item to sumOfDigitsInEvenPlaces.

This seems slightly more verbose, but also more readable, to me than Anonymous' (accepted) answer. However, benchmarks to come.

---

Well, the compiler seems to think my code more understandable as well, since he removes it all if I don't print the results (which explains why I kept getting a time of 0 all along...). The other code though is obfuscated enough for even the compiler.

In the end, even with huge arrays, it's pretty hard for clock_t to tell the difference between the two. You get about a third less instructions in the second case, but since everything's in cache (and your running sums even in registers) it doesn't matter much.

For the curious, I've put the disassembly of both versions (compiled from C) here : http://pastebin.com/2fciLEMw